# Convert row into column in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am using sql server and srss my sql query returns

[image]

the result should be

[image]

but SUBJECT_STATUS column values unknowen for every query result

**how can i obtain the result in SSRS not in sql server**?

Comment: This looks like a simple matrix report - what's your problem

Comment: How can i implement it?@p-salmon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

select toolbox, drag matrix into design pane
select report data, drag subject_name into rows, drag subject-status into columns, drag student_count into data.
Preview.
When happy build and deploy.

Comment: @Hossam Elsagheer have you had a chance to look at this solution?

Comment: thanks ,it works, but one last thing : RowNumber is not correct why? it starts with 2 ,4,5,7. i will try RunningValue

Comment: `=RunningValue(CountDistinct("Tablix1"),count,"Tablix1")` it is OK

Answer (score 0):

Using conditional aggregation with `CASE EXPRESSION` :

```
SELECT t.subject_name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.subject_status = 1 THEN t.student_count END) as first,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.subject_status = 2 THEN t.student_count END) as second,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.subject_status = 3 THEN t.student_count END) as third,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.subject_status = 4 THEN t.student_count END) as fourth
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY t.subject_name
```

Comment: but i do not know the number of subject_status in advance

Comment: What's the range it can be? I don't understand.. this should return the exact same output as your example . @HossamElsagheer

Comment: subject_status values come from database ,so its values are unknown

Answer (score 0):

The required result can be obtained using pivot and dynamic sql.

```
DECLARE @statusList varchar(500)
select distinct '['+ cast(SUBJECT_STATUS as varchar)+']' as subject_status
into temp
FROM YourTable
select @statusList= COALESCE(@statusList + ',', '')+ cast(SUBJECT_STATUS as varchar)
FROM temp
drop table temp
DECLARE @sql varchar(1000)
SET @sql = '
select * from
(select STUDENT_COUNT,SUBJECT_NAME,SUBJECT_STATUS 
from YourTable) sub
pivot (
sum(STUDENT_COUNT) 
FOR SUBJECT_STATUS
IN ('+@statusList+')
) piv;'
EXEC (@sql)
```

[Working demo here](http://rextester.com/SNB40738)

Comment: how can i obtain the result in SSRS not in sql server?